# Why too many empty sections result in a mess without pagebreak?

Tags: pdftex

When I wrote a template, I found that if there is too many empty sections in a chapter, `latex` will not produce appropriate page breaks. All these sections will just be listed in a single page. Why does that happen?

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chp1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\section{sec1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because latex tries hard to avoid a page break *after*  the title of a section. Put some dummy text between the sections.

Comment: the "text" @UlrikeFischer refers to can be invisible `\mbox{}` would be enough.

Comment: the reason for this is given in this answer: [Overfull box and broken pagination](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57861/579)