# Latex can not change page automatically

Tags: page-breaking

If I only input the section title but no body text, Latex can not start new page automatically. The following is my minimal work.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\part{Title of Part I}
\chapter{Title of chapter a}
\section{section-1}
\section{section-2}
\section{section-3}
\section{section-4}
\section{section-5}
\section{section-6}
\section{section-7}
\section{section-8}
\section{section-9}
\section{section-10}

\section{section-11}
\section{section-12}
\section{section-13}
\section{section-14}
\section{section-15}
\section{section-16}
\section{section-17}
\section{section-18}
\section{section-19}
\section{section-20}

\end{document}
```

Comment: duplicate here: [Overfull box and broken pagination](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57861)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

LaTeX prevents a page break right after `\section` to avoid a single section title at the bottom of the previous page.

Just add some dummy text until the section text is written, e.g.:

```
\part{Title of Part I}
\chapter{Title of chapter a}
\section{section-1}
TODO
\section{section-2}
TODO
```

...