# Meeting Minute with supervisor

Tags: tables, formatting

I want to make a table of **Meeting Minutes** with supervisor. The format is as follow;

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Meeting#-------------Roll#-----------Meeting Date---------Minutes
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Summary of Discussion:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The code below is only for header of meetings, but I don't know how I include **Summary of Discussion** paragraph in this table....

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{2cm}||p{3cm}||p{6cm}|  }
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Meeting Minutes}} \\
\hline
\hline
\textbf{Meeting no}& \textbf{Roll no}&\textbf{Meeting Date}&\textbf{Duration}\\
\hline
{1}& {112}&{17-04-2014}&{30 Minutes}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please include a code of your efforts?

Comment: @Malipivo, I edit the question now, actuall I want the code of this table. thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried the table?

Comment: @percusse, I almost done, but I don't know how the set table format for **Summary of Discussion** part,because it is cover all the space as table width and it also include text.

Comment: If you provide the incomplete code then we can try to fix your already existing table instead of wasting effort trying to guess what it might be.

Comment: @percusse, I provide the code now.

Comment: You might want to use the package [`minutes`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minutes), which is dedicated for this purpose. Or see [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7191/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sort of hack that I have stolen from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99333/22492) answer. Note that you might better to go with [minutes](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minutes) package as @strpeter have suggested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{2cm}||p{3cm}||p{6cm}|  }
        \hline
        \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Meeting Minutes}} \\
        \hline
        \hline
            \textbf{Meeting no}& \textbf{Roll no}&\textbf{Meeting Date}&\textbf{Duration}\\
        \hline
            {1}& {112}&{17-04-2014}&{30 Minutes}\\
        \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Summary of Discussion:}} \\ 
            \multicolumn{4}{|p{15cm+2\tabcolsep}|}{\lipsum[1]} \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I changed `documentclass` to `article` because meeting minutes of book-size wouldn't be so minutes `;)`.

[image]